# Apache Rewrite regular expressions for dynamically generated URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I trying to do a rewrite for a dynamically generated url. My problem is that i can't find the right regular expression syntax to check for:

A **word** or it could be a **number then a word** or it could be a **number then / then a number then a word** or finally it could be **2 words that are hyphenated**.  I wondered if i need to write multiple rewrites each one for each instance??

Here's an example of my rewrite and some examples of the character sets i need to compare.

```
RewriteRule ^search/strand/([???]+)$ ?p=search&strand=$1
```

classics, 30 theatre, 45/50 playhouse, studio/film 1, friday fight-night

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder if you can provide an example of what you tried and/or need?

Comment: At least provide sample URIs that you want to rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i sorted it with this syntax, but if it could be done better i'd like to know so please comment with ideas.

Taking my example above, the write is the same:

```
RewriteRule ^search/strand/([???]+)$ ?p=search&strand=$1
```

and regular expressions for

- **classics** [a-z]+
- **30 theatre** [0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+
- **45/50 playhouse** [0-9]+/+[0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+
- **studio/film 1** [a-z]+/+[a-z]+[\s]+[0-9]+
- **friday fight-night** [0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+[\W]+[a-z]+

Then just chain them together with **|** so that the resulting rewrite looks like:

```
RewriteRule ^search/strand/([a-z]+|[0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+|[0-9]+\/+[0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+|[a-z]+\/+[a-z]+[\s]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[\s]+[a-z]+[\W]+[a-z]+)$ ?p=search&strand=$1
```